# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: adb

I'm trying to install ISIS on my nexus 5. I downloaded the apk file but adb install says INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY. How can I install what is missing?

```
$ adb install com.isis.mclient.atnt.activity.apk 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
7279 KB/s (18120454 bytes in 2.430s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.isis.mclient.atnt.activity.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @NickRuiz No. I didn't.

Comment: I'd contact the developer, asking for dependencies (include your error report). Dev should now what is needed.